# Custom Campaign tracking Cross-Domain Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, analytics, google-tag-manager, analytics.js

I have successfully implemented Cross-Domain tracking with Google Analytics (1 session as user jumps across domain, same _ga cookie on both domains, etc.) However, when the user jumps to the second domain and completes a purchase, the eCommerce transaction is not getting attributed to the utm custom campaign from the first page. It seems you can't pass the utm custom campaign information cross-domain. Is this true? Has anyone ran into this before?

Comment: This shouldn't be the case if cross-domain tracking is setup correctly. Are you able to link to the domains? Or provide more information on the steps you've taken to implement cross-domain tracking?

Comment: what you mean with 'utm custom campaign information cross-domain'? What is the source / medium of the transactions?

Comment: They were direct/none for any transactions from site2.com even though site1.com had utm parameters of source/medium set. This was cleared up from a complete cookie/cache clear. My solution is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue, cache. I have done hard refreshes before every test, but I went into Chrome tools and clear EVERYTHING. Cookie, cache, everything. And Cross-Domain tracking for Custom Campaigns started working! For reference here are the scripts for the two sites:

```html
Site 1:

ga('create','UA-xxxxxxx-x'','auto', { 'allowLinker': true });
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['site2.com']);
ga('require','ecommerce','ecommerce.js');
ga('send','pageview');

Site2:

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto', { 'name': 'client', 'allowLinker': true });
ga('client.require', 'linker');
ga('client.linker:autoLink', ['site1.com']);
ga('client.require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('client.send', 'pageview');
```

Also, I added site1.com and site2.com to the Referral Exclusion List in GA and the UA key for site 1 and site 2 are the same.